# making JavaScript generated content possible for search engines to index

Tags: javascript, search-engine, seo

Is there any way to make JavaScript generated content indexable by search engines? I remember reading something about Google parsing a generated site map, but I might be wrong here.

_L

Comment: Sitemaps will only let you include URLs afaik: http://www.sitemaps.org/ . If your javascript generated content is retrieved via ajax you may obviously link to the source via sitemaps. So, sitemaps may well be a step in the right direction for you but not a real solution.

Answer (score 1):

I also remember reading something similar when searching for a history plugin for jQuery. You might check out:

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/11/spiders-view-of-web-20.html

The explanation of hash links and actual href links sounds about right.

Comment: I agree, and the emphasis should be on Progressive Enhancement. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement

Answer (score 0):

Mostly the search engine spiders do not render javascript so any content will not be seen.